# Python Compare Two Different Object Array

Tags: python

I am trying to compare two different items of two different arrays in Python 3. For big sized arrays I encountered an annoying performance issues.

I searched the Internet a bit just to found out that all said methods want me to loop first array, then loop second list and compare items in them.

Is there any better way for this?

An exapmle code:

```
array1 = [[1233, 56, 77], [3123, 321, 22], [2131, 43, 12]]
array2 = [[3213, 11], [4312, 22], [4253, 33], [8767, 44]]

for item1 in array1:
    for item2 in array2:
        if item2[1] < item1[1] and item2[1] < item1[2] and \
            item1[0] + 1000 >= item2[0] >= item1[0]:
                comparisonOutput.append([item2[0], item1[0], item2[0] - item1[0], item2[1], item1[1] - item2[1], item1[2] - item2[1]])
```

Comment: Sort the two arrays ahead of time.  Then you can terminate your loop when applicable. Example, if item[0] + 1000 > item2[0] is false, you know it won't be true in the next iteration if the next item2 element has a greater first index.

Comment: I should divide my condition code to four rather than coding it at once, am I right?

Comment: If anything, you should put the condition most likely to fail first.  Then future "and" conditions won't be evaluated.  Difficult to help further without having any context regarding the data.